# Trying to run a batch file from another program and redirecting the output

Tags: batch-file, syntax, parameters

I have a method to run a batch file with a list of parameters. Those parameters are sent to the batch file and the batch file calls another program that needs the parameter set up in a certain way:

```
start test --entities=%entities% --tags=%out% --start=%start% --end=%end% --interval=%interval% --wide>%output%
```

Where output is the file I want the results of running:

> ```
> test --entities=%entities% --tags=%out% --start=%start% --end=%end% --interval=%interval% --wide
> ```

To be placed but I keep getting `1>` instead of `>` when I run the file.

Answer (score 1):

`>` is just a short form of `1>` (`1` means `STDOUT` = Standard output stream). Command repetition will insert the `1` for you, if you didn't write it. That's  neither a failure nor a problem.

Your actual problem is, that you redirect the output of the `start` command - which is empy.

To redirect the output of your batchfile, use

```
start test --entities=%entities% --tags=%out% --start=%start% --end=%end% --interval=%interval% --wide ^>%output%
```

You might want to try, if

```
call test --entities=%entities% --tags=%out% --start=%start% --end=%end% --interval=%interval% --wide >%output%
```

works even better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ryan's Guide to Piping and Redirection: http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php .